# Video as a text background with another video background underneath

Tags: html, css, video, background, frontend

I'm trying to create a text with a video as a background (inside the letters) and another background video underneath the whole box. I can't manage to make the first video only visible inside the letters of the selected word without any other background (like the black one I've put on the snippet) and making the other video visible for the rest of the BG space.

Any idea? thanks!

That's the point:

[image]

```css
.main-title { height: auto; margin: 0 0 8em; color: white; overflow: hidden; position: relative; background: radial-gradient(at left 50%, #5383fb57, #5383fb17); }

.main-title video#main-video { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; object-fit: cover; padding: 0; z-index: -2; }

.main-title h1 { font-weight: 700; font-size: 70px; line-height: 63px; color: white; }

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}

.container > .bg-video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* background-color and color should be the same as the below otherwise it won't work */
.container > .text {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* Mix Blend Mode does the all magic */
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-title col-12 col-lg-6 d-block">
        <h1>Lorem 
        <!-- <div class="main-title-color">
            <span>Hiring</span>
            <video id="title-video" src="/img/title-BG.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        </div> -->
        <div class="container">
            <video class="bg-video" autoplay loop>
              <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1FY5Zqz9z703SGe6XE4lNkExCHrUbnX6y" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            <div class="text">Ipsum</div>
        </div>
        <br>dolor</h1>
        </div>
        <video class="bg-video" autoplay loop>
              <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1etvHjbNQ1W2fX2z5Jz0C2CZLl_EgYVfn" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this solved now? Share your solution or else I can show you if it's still needed.

Comment: @VC.One - it's still needed

Comment: @Yaroslav See if the posted is useful to you. You can experiment with settings (How to position text by Canvas settings (Xpos, Ypos)? How to position text by Div settings (top, left positioning)? etc etc. Ask anything if stuck with editing. PS: The code uses `z-index` to position items in layers (one above another).

Answer (score 1):

> *"...Trying to create a text with a video as a background (*ie:* inside the letters) and also another background video underneath."*

You can mask a video (control which parts are visible) by using an **Alpha mask** (sometimes called an Opacity mask or a Transparency mask).

Research: [CSS mask-image](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=css+mask-image).

Usually the CSS `mask-image` mask comes from using a loaded PNG image, but you can also create a mask **dynamically** using text (or even pixels) written into the Canvas element. This means:

- Write text into Canvas using `.fillText("myText", X_pos, Y_pos );`
- Convert the Canvas into an Image object using `canvas.toDataURL();`
- Create a custom CSS variable like `var(--myVar);` which holds path to mask (an Image).
- Use the Image object's path (**DataURL**) as an input for your mask variable in CSS using: 
  ``` .style.setProperty('--myVar', ``url(``+my_dataURL+``)``); ```. 
  *note:* replace those shown double ``` `` ``` with a single version.

To see the concept in action, test-run this snippet below:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = "bold 200px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Lorem", 0, ( canvas.height * 0.50) );

ctx.font = "bold 270px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Ipsum", 0, ( canvas.height * 0.85) );

//# convert Canvas to Image (usable as <img> tag content)
let my_dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

// Get the root element
var doc_root = document.querySelector(':root');
doc_root.style.setProperty('--custom_txt_img', `url(`+my_dataURL+`)`);
```

```css
:root
{ --custom_txt_img: url( "" ); }

.my_text_mask 
{
    mask-mode: alpha;

    mask-image: var(--custom_txt_img);
    mask-size: 70%;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;

    -webkit-mask-image: var(--custom_txt_img);
    -webkit-mask-size: 70%;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="container">

<!-- BACKGROUND VIDEO (UNDER TEXT) -->
<div style="z-index: 0; overflow:hidden; position: absolute; width: 100%;">
    <video width="100%" muted autoplay loop>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
<div>

<!-- TEXT MASK (SHOWS VIDEO INSIDE TEXT) -->
<div class="my_text_mask"  style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; width: 60%; top: 12%; left: 10%">
    <video width="90%" muted autoplay loop>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    
    <canvas id="canvas" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px" width="900" height="600">
    </canvas>
</div>

<!-- (White) TEXT ABOVE VIDEO -->
<text style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; top: 60%; left: 10%; font-size: 200%; color: #FFFFFF;" >
Dolores 
</text>

</div>

</body>
```

Here is the code as a complete testable document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

:root
{ --custom_txt_img: url( "" ); }

.my_text_mask 
{
    mask-mode: alpha;

    mask-image: var(--custom_txt_img);
    mask-size: 70%;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;

    -webkit-mask-image: var(--custom_txt_img);
    -webkit-mask-size: 70%;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}

</style>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <!-- BACKGROUND VIDEO (UNDER TEXT) -->
    <div style="z-index: 0; overflow:hidden; position: absolute; width: 100%;">
        <video width="100%" muted autoplay loop>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    <div>

    <!-- TEXT MASK (SHOWS VIDEO INSIDE TEXT) -->
    <div class="my_text_mask"  style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; width: 60%; top: 12%; left: 10%">
        <video width="90%" muted autoplay loop>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        
        <canvas id="canvas" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px" width="900" height="600">
        </canvas>
    </div>

    <!-- (White) TEXT ABOVE VIDEO -->
    <text style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; top: 60%; left: 10%; font-size: 200%; color: #FFFFFF;" >
    Dolores 
    </text>

</div>

</body>

<script>

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = "bold 200px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Lorem", 0, ( canvas.height * 0.50) );

ctx.font = "bold 270px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Ipsum", 0, ( canvas.height * 0.85) );

//# convert Canvas to Image (usable as <img> tag content)
let my_dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

// Get the root element
var doc_root = document.querySelector(':root');
doc_root.style.setProperty('--custom_txt_img', `url(`+my_dataURL+`)`);

</script>
```